# Twitter Bootstrap Carousel skipping issue

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

On the site I'm working on the carousel seems to skip to the third image the first time you click on the next button when the page loads. Does anyone have any ideas as to why this is? I'm following the suggested layout from [the bootstrap documentation](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#carousel).

Comment: Side note: You might want to add the [bootstrap-transition.js](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap-transition.js) plugin in order to use CSS3 transitions when sliding. The carousel plugin will utilize it automatically.  However, it is optional.

Comment: I am Experiencing the same issue in IE8, I checked to see that bootstrap.js contains the transition, i also tried re-instantiating the carousel on page load... any other ideas?

Answer (score 5):

There seems to be a problem with the initialization of the carousel.

When you click for the first time on the arrow, it initializes the carousel which triggers the first switch AND select the next slide because you clicked on the arrow (all at the same time).

A direct fix would be to add this code to initialize the carousel on loading (which also enable the automatic sliding) :

```js
$(function() {
    $('#myCarousel').carousel();
});
```

Be sure to include this after the plugin and everything should be okay.

#### Update

It also appears to be jumping to the 3rd **only** without the transition effect.

As suggested by *merv* you could include the `bootstrap-transition.js` file and it will resolve your problem.

Anyway, I submitted a ticket, for those who wants some follow-up : [Issue on github](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/4205)

Comment: Hmm. That's surprising—I didn't expect adding the CSS3 transitions to fix it.  I suspect that the `slide()` method is still getting called twice, only that when using transitions, the `sliding===true` flag will short circuit it and ignore the second call.  I actually wouldn't advocate *only* adding the **bootstrap-transition.js**.  I think initializing the carousel, as you first suggested, is the better practice.